# Removing duplicate consecutive data from a MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table which stores time-series data - essentially, temperature and humidity samples from a number of sensors taken at (relatively) regular intervals.

Each sensor's values are stored to the table (along with the sensor's id) on a regular basis, whether or not the recorded temperature and humidity has changed. This has created a relatively large table, so I've updated the application to only store a value for a sensor when it's recorded value changes - it will now store two rows with the before and after sensor values when a value changes (this allows the charting code to remain unchanged).

Now, I want to tidy up the old data to remove any consecutive duplicate readings from a particular sensor, keeping only the rows which represent the first time a new sensor value was recorded, or the last time the sensor value was recorded. Effectively, this is just removing redundant data.

I've tried constructing a query for this, but as the primary key is not consecutive for a particular single sensor, I'm having trouble identifying the duplicate rows I can delete.

This is better illustrated using an extract of the data - I've marked the rows I want to keep in bold and added a note describing why I want to keep that specific row.

```
+-----+----------+---------------------+-------------+----------+
| id  | sensorid | datetime            | temperature | humidity |
+-----+----------+---------------------+-------------+----------+
| 818 | E9       | 2012-10-23 20:59:03 |       20.00 |       72 | First val for E9
| 819 | C3       | 2012-10-23 20:59:19 |       19.50 |       69 | First val for C3
| 820 | E9       | 2012-10-23 20:59:47 |       20.00 |       72 |
| 821 | C3       | 2012-10-23 21:00:00 |       19.50 |       69 |
| 822 | E9       | 2012-10-23 21:00:29 |       20.00 |       72 |
| 823 | C3       | 2012-10-23 21:00:41 |       19.50 |       69 |
| 824 | E9       | 2012-10-23 21:01:12 |       20.00 |       72 |
| 825 | C3       | 2012-10-23 21:01:22 |       19.50 |       69 |
| 826 | E9       | 2012-10-23 21:01:55 |       20.00 |       72 |
| 827 | C3       | 2012-10-23 21:02:03 |       19.50 |       69 |
| 828 | E9       | 2012-10-23 21:02:38 |       20.00 |       72 |
| 829 | C3       | 2012-10-23 21:02:44 |       19.50 |       69 |
| 830 | E9       | 2012-10-23 21:03:21 |       20.00 |       72 |
| 831 | C3       | 2012-10-23 21:03:25 |       19.50 |       69 |
| 832 | E9       | 2012-10-23 21:04:04 |       20.00 |       72 |
| 833 | C3       | 2012-10-23 21:04:06 |       19.50 |       69 |
| 834 | EC       | 2012-10-23 21:04:32 |       13.90 |       91 | First val for EC
| 835 | EC       | 2012-10-23 21:04:32 |       13.90 |       91 |
| 836 | C3       | 2012-10-23 21:04:47 |       19.50 |       69 |
| 837 | E9       | 2012-10-23 21:04:47 |       20.00 |       72 |
| 838 | EC       | 2012-10-23 21:05:11 |       13.90 |       91 |
| 839 | C3       | 2012-10-23 21:05:28 |       19.50 |       69 |
| 840 | E9       | 2012-10-23 21:05:31 |       20.00 |       72 |
| 841 | EC       | 2012-10-23 21:05:50 |       13.90 |       91 |
| 842 | C3       | 2012-10-23 21:06:09 |       19.50 |       69 |
| 843 | E9       | 2012-10-23 21:06:13 |       20.00 |       72 | The last time E9 has a temp of 20
| 844 | EC       | 2012-10-23 21:06:29 |       13.90 |       91 |
| 845 | C3       | 2012-10-23 21:06:50 |       19.50 |       69 |
| 846 | E9       | 2012-10-23 21:06:56 |       19.90 |       72 | The first time E9 has a temp of 19.9
| 847 | EC       | 2012-10-23 21:07:08 |       13.90 |       91 |
| 848 | C3       | 2012-10-23 21:07:31 |       19.50 |       69 |
| 849 | E9       | 2012-10-23 21:07:39 |       19.90 |       72 |
| 850 | EC       | 2012-10-23 21:07:47 |       13.90 |       91 |
| 851 | C3       | 2012-10-23 21:08:12 |       19.50 |       69 |
| 852 | E9       | 2012-10-23 21:08:22 |       19.90 |       72 |
| 853 | EC       | 2012-10-23 21:08:26 |       13.90 |       91 |
| 854 | C3       | 2012-10-23 21:08:53 |       19.50 |       69 |
| 855 | EC       | 2012-10-23 21:09:05 |       13.90 |       91 |
| 856 | E9       | 2012-10-23 21:09:05 |       19.90 |       72 |
| 857 | C3       | 2012-10-23 21:09:34 |       19.50 |       69 | The last time C3 has a temp of 19.5 
| 858 | EC       | 2012-10-23 21:09:44 |       13.90 |       91 |
| 859 | E9       | 2012-10-23 21:09:49 |       19.90 |       72 |
| 860 | C3       | 2012-10-23 21:10:15 |       19.60 |       69 | The first time C3 has a temp of 19.6 
| 861 | EC       | 2012-10-23 21:10:23 |       13.90 |       91 |
| 862 | E9       | 2012-10-23 21:10:32 |       19.90 |       72 |
| 863 | EC       | 2012-10-23 21:11:02 |       13.90 |       91 |
| 864 | C3       | 2012-10-23 21:11:37 |       19.60 |       69 |
| 865 | E9       | 2012-10-23 21:11:58 |       19.90 |       72 | Last val for E9
| 866 | C3       | 2012-10-23 21:12:18 |       19.60 |       69 | Last val for C3
| 867 | EC       | 2012-10-23 21:12:20 |       13.90 |       91 | Last val for EC
+-----+----------+---------------------+-------------+----------+
```

Comment: Do you actually need to delete the "superfluous" records from the underlying table, or are you simply seeking to fetch a filtered/reduced resultset?

Comment: I'd like to delete them, but if I can fetch a reduced resultset, I can use that to populate a replacement table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [user variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/user-variables.html) to track the "last" values of the `sensorid`, `temperature` and `humidity` columns (when sorting the entire table by `sensor` and `datetime`), one can identify to which "group" each record belongs and then aggregate on that basis:

```
SELECT sensorid, temperature, humidity,
       MIN(datetime) dt_min, MAX(datetime) dt_max
FROM (
  SELECT   datetime,
           @group := @group + IF(
             @last_sensor   <=> sensorid
         AND @last_temp     <=> temperature
         AND @last_humidity <=> humidity
           , 0, 1) gp,
             @last_sensor   :=  sensorid    sensorid,
             @last_temp     :=  temperature temperature,
             @last_humidity :=  humidity    humidity
  FROM     my_table, (SELECT
             @group         :=  0,
             @last_sensor   :=  NULL,
             @last_temp     :=  NULL,
             @last_humidity :=  NULL
           ) init
  ORDER BY sensorid, datetime
) t GROUP BY t.gp
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a8f6/1/0).

One could perform an anti-join with this query to delete all other records from the original table:

```
DELETE my_table.*
FROM   my_table LEFT JOIN (
         <above query>
       ) x
   ON  my_table.sensorid    = x.sensorid
   AND my_table.temperature = x.temperature
   AND my_table.humidity    = x.humidity
   AND my_table.datetime IN (x.dt_min, x.dt_max)
WHERE x.sensorid IS NULL
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc86f/1/0).

Note that where two (identical) readings were taken from the same sensor at the same `datetime`, it is not clear which of the records should be kept/deleted (especially since you noted that "*the primary key is not consecutive for a particular single sensor*"): thus the above query will leaves record `id = 835` intact.

Comment: Strangely, running the query with the table from your sqlfiddle causes a "ERROR 1055 (42000): 't.sensorid' isn't in GROUP BY" message on my local MySQL server (5.1.70-log)

Comment: @IanGregory: You must have the [`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) mode enabled.  Either disable it, or else `GROUP BY t.gp, t.sensorid, t.temperature, t.humidity`.

Comment: Thanks - ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY was new to me.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to join each record to check it's previous and next temperature:

```
SELECT t.id,
       t.sensorid,
       t.temperature,
       t.comment,
       prev.id prev_id,
       prev.temperature prev_temp,
       next.id next_id,
       next.temperature next_temp
FROM table1 t
LEFT JOIN table1 prev
  ON prev.id = ( SELECT max(id)
                 FROM table1 t1
                 WHERE t1.sensorid = t.sensorid
                   AND t1.id < t.id
                )
LEFT JOIN table1 next
  ON next.id =  ( SELECT min(id)
                  FROM table1 t1
                  WHERE t1.sensorid = t.sensorid
                    AND t1.id > t.id
                )
ORDER BY t.sensorid, t.id
;
```

Demo --> http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/297ab/4

Using this query you can get records that need to be deleted, checking this condition:

```
current-row-temperature = previous-temperature 
   AND
current-row-temperature = next-temperature
```

the query is:

```
SELECT t.id,
       t.sensorid,
       t.temperature,
       t.comment,
       prev.id prev_id,
       prev.temperature prev_temp,
       next.id next_id,
       next.temperature next_temp
FROM table1 t
LEFT JOIN table1 prev
  ON prev.id = ( SELECT max(id)
                 FROM table1 t1
                 WHERE t1.sensorid = t.sensorid
                   AND t1.id < t.id
                )
LEFT JOIN table1 next
  ON next.id =  ( SELECT min(id)
                  FROM table1 t1
                  WHERE t1.sensorid = t.sensorid
                    AND t1.id > t.id
                )
WHERE t.temperature = prev.temperature
  AND t.temperature = next.temperature
ORDER BY t.sensorid, t.id
;
```

The query can be used as a subquery in multitable delete:

```
DETELE table1 t1, 
(
   the above query 
) x1
WHERE t1.id = x1.id
```

you can also negate that condition to retrieve only records that you want to keep.

```
SELECT t.id,
       t.sensorid,
       t.temperature,
       t.comment,
       prev.id prev_id,
       prev.temperature prev_temp,
       next.id next_id,
       next.temperature next_temp
FROM table1 t
LEFT JOIN table1 prev
  ON prev.id = ( SELECT max(id)
                 FROM table1 t1
                 WHERE t1.sensorid = t.sensorid
                   AND t1.id < t.id
                )
LEFT JOIN table1 next
  ON next.id =  ( SELECT min(id)
                  FROM table1 t1
                  WHERE t1.sensorid = t.sensorid
                    AND t1.id > t.id
                )
WHERE t.temperature <> prev.temperature
   OR t.temperature <> next.temperature
   OR prev.temperature IS NULL
   OR next.temperature IS NULL
ORDER BY t.sensorid, t.id
;
```

You can use this query to copy selected records to a new table:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS
SELECT t.*
FROM table1 t
LEFT JOIN table1 prev
  ON prev.id = ( SELECT max(id)
                 FROM table1 t1
                 WHERE t1.sensorid = t.sensorid
                   AND t1.id < t.id
                )
LEFT JOIN table1 next
  ON next.id =  ( SELECT min(id)
                  FROM table1 t1
                  WHERE t1.sensorid = t.sensorid
                    AND t1.id > t.id
                )
WHERE t.temperature <> prev.temperature
   OR t.temperature <> next.temperature
   OR prev.temperature IS NULL
   OR next.temperature IS NULL
ORDER BY t.sensorid, t.id
;
```

Comment: One of the great things about SO is getting two excellent answers to a problem within a few minutes of answering a question. Thanks.